# Null Password Char in Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have a `textbox` in a c# windows form i am having problems in assigning a null values to a `PasswordChar`. What i want to do is that if a `checkbox` is checked then the `PasswordChar` should be `null` i.e the actual text should be displayed else the `PasswordChar` should be `*`. This what i have tried

```
    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            txtPassword.PasswordChar = '*';
        }
        else
        {
            txtPassword.PasswordChar = '';
        }
    }
```

but this line

```
     txtPassword.PasswordChar = '';
```

is generating an error. I have even tried

```
     txtPassword.PasswordChar = null;
```

but i still get an error.

Please help me correct my code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To reset `PassswordChar`, do this `txtPassword.PasswordChar = '\0';`

For your convenience:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
   txtPassword.PasswordChar = checkBox1.Checked ? '*' : '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

using this code to set null Password character

```
textBox1.PasswordChar = (char)0;
```

or this

```
textBox1.PasswordChar = '\0';
```

Answer (score 1):

For additional infomation:

There is an alternative in `TextBox.PasswordChar`, you can also use `TextBox.UseSystemPasswordChar`.

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
   textBox1.UseSystemPasswordChar = checkBox1.Checked ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: works perfect, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try reading the manual for [`TextBox.PasswordChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.passwordchar.aspx)?

> Set the value of this property to 0 (character value) if you do not want the control to mask characters as they are typed.